# Meteor/Mongo Failure to load data from aggregate/pipeline

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregate, pipeline

Error on server console: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Meteor 1.8.1

Project worked fine at 1.6.x, MongoDB 3.2.x

mlab pushed me to mongo 3.6.x and now some of my charts (chart.js) and tables (aslagle:reactive-table) aren’t working.

Both of these are generated via aggregate/pipeline (example below).

Long story short, I’ve neglected this project for several months and just getting back to it, ran into this issue, and tried updating to 1.8.1. Which has me at mongo 4.0.6

Charts and tables still not working and I think it’s because I’m missing some update to the syntax/structure in the aggregates and/or pipelines. I could very well be wrong here as I’m rusty, not a dev by trade and as mentioned haven’t touched this in a few months.

Here’s one failing aggregate/pipeline that’s used to draw a line chart (Chart.js):

```
pointTrendsSprt: function(uid, sp){
    var pipeline = [
                        { $match: {"userId": uid, "sport":sp, "slate": {$exists: true} } },
                        { $project: {slate:1, sport:1, pointsWon:1, createdAt:1} },
                        { $group: {
                                    _id: "$slate",
                                    sport: {"$addToSet": "$sport"},
                                    pointsWon: {"$sum": "$pointsWon"},
                                    createdAt: {"$max": "$createdAt"}
                                  } 
                        },
                        { $sort: { "createdAt":1 } }
                    ];

    return Results.aggregate(pipeline);
},
```

Here’s another that’s used in a aslagle:reactive-table:

```
allXteam: function(uid){
    var pipeline = [
                        { $match: {"userId": uid, "win": "true"} },
                        { $project: {team:1, match:1, play:1, Count: "$count"} },
                        { $group: 
                            {_id: "$team", 
                            play: {"$addToSet": "$play"},
                            count:{$sum:1}} 
                        }
                    ];

    return Picks.aggregate( pipeline );

},
```

Both of these are in a methods.js file in the server folder. I use Meteor.call on the client side js file to set session vars where the chart and tables pull from.

As mentioned, I think I need to fix something in my aggregations/pipelines but tried adding in “cursor” and “explain” and am either not doing that right or just wrong in that assumption.

Any suggestions/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Results returned by aggregate command changed with Meteor 1.7. See here for details : https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#breakingchanges-8

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I did find a solution that matches what you shared, but neglected to update it here, so in case it helps anyone I've added it as an "answer" below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [this solution](https://forums.meteor.com/t/getting-a-error-on-aggregation-method-call/45224) worked:

Collection.rawCollection().aggregate().toArray()

Here's my final re-factoring (although I will have to look into that 'Meteor.wrapAsync' form:

```
allXteam: async function(uid){
    var pipeline = [
                        { $match: {"userId": uid, "win": "true"} },
                        { $project: {team:1, match:1, play:1, Count: "$count"} },
                        { $group: 
                            {_id: "$team", 
                            play: {"$addToSet": "$play"},
                            count:{$sum:1}} 
                        }
                    ];

    const aXt = await Picks.rawCollection().aggregate( pipeline ).toArray();

    return aXt;
```